# quickest way to assign values of keys which are intersection in the target and source object

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, react-redux, assign

I want to assign only those keys which are already present in the target object and not the other keys that are done by the object.assign method.

```
example
a = { x: 2}
b = {x:3, y:4}

then result = {x:3}
```

I know there are other ways in past but is there any newer and better ways to do this like in one line?

Comment: *"but is there any newer and better ways to do this like in one line?"* "Better" in terms of ... what? You can turn any solution into a "on-line" solution by adding semicolons and removing line breaks.

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the keys of the `target` object to a new object by taking the values from the `obj` if they exist:

```js
const fn = (target, obj) => Object.keys(target)
  .reduce((acc, key) => key in obj 
    ? { ...acc, [key]: obj[key] } 
    : acc
  , {})

const a = { x: 2}
const b = { x:3, y:4 }

const result = fn(a, b)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: thanks, but I want a better way. With less code.

Comment: @xxxhomie21 less code does not mean *better*. And this isn't a code golf site. We aim for *useful* solutions, not just the most fanciful.

Answer (score 0):

I think the fastest way is:

```js
for (let key in b) {
  if (a[key] === undefined) {
    delete b[key];
  }
}
```

Comment: If want to be really correct you'd have to use `if (!(key in a))` because `undefined` is a valid value.